# Excel: I want to extract characters from 1 column and paste these into a separate column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Looking at the image below I want to extract the Lats and Longs from the "geohash,latitude,longitude" column.

I can't just use the function `RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-8)` because the Lats & Longs are different lengths and I'll have to go through the entire column E manually adding any numbers that have been removed.

[image: Example picture:]

Comment: You mean to say you want to extract Latitude and Longitude from Column C  in Column  D (Latitude) and E (Longitude) ?

Comment: I just want to extract the Latitudes and Longitudes from Column C

Comment: @wilga,, just check I've posted a single Formula Solution. Hope you find is useful.

Comment: Can you / would you write a VBA function?

Answer (score 11):

1. Select the whole column and copy it on the next empty column, suppose it is column`E`.
2. Select Column `E`.
3. Go to Data -> Text To Columns.

[image]

4. Select Delimited

[image]

5. Select Comma,

[image]

6. Click Next and Finish

Answer (score 4):

You can use **FIND**, **MID** & **LEFT** Functions for this.

Use this for Lat:

```
=LEFT(MID(C1,FIND(",",C1)+1,100),FIND(",",MID(C1,FIND(",",C1)+1,100))-1)
```

& Use this for Long:

```
=MID(MID(C1,FIND(",",C1)+1,100),FIND(",",MID(C1,FIND(",",C1)+1,100))+1,100)
```

Then simply drag them both down.

If you want to return them as Integers, use `+0` at the end of the formulas, else they will be strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FIND()`-function to get the position of the commas and after that split the string for latitude and longitude.

So can use for latitude
`=MID(A2, FIND(",", A2)+1, FIND(",", A2, FIND(",", A2)+1)-1)`

and for longitude
`=RIGHT(A2, LENGTH(A2)-FIND(",", A2, FIND(",", A2)+1))`

Answer (score 2):

**This single Formula will extract both Latitude and Longitude.**

In **Cell D2** write this Formula.

[image]

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($C2,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($C:C)*998,999))
```

**NB:** Finish with Enter you find the Latitude then just drag or Copy the Formula to adjacent Cell (one cell Right) you get Longitude and finally drag it down till is necessary.

*I do believe this help you.*